# I want a string length multiple of 8 and remove any extra digits in the string

Tags: javascript, string, logic

I want a string to return a length of multiple of 8 for example if I've 123456789
so here I need to return a string 12345678 removing the last digit
Example 2:
for instance string length is 123456789123=>here it should remove 9123 and return me 1234
5678

I'm returning a string length when I pass the length of string to be 8 the length that are not multiple of 8 I should make them multiple of 8 by removing the exessive characters

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it is what you want

```js
let str = "1234567887654321deleted"

function get8Multiple(tobehandlestring){
  let len = str.length
  if (len <= 8) return tobehandlestring;
  
  let extra = len % 8;
  
  return tobehandlestring.substring(0, len-extra);
  
}

console.log(get8Multiple(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example for your reference

```
var a = '1234567891231234567891236';
console.log(a.substring(8*Math.floor(a.length/8), 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you haven't posted any of your own attempts to solve this, here's a starter:

The [Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator comes in handy.

1. Get the full length of the string
2. apply the remainder operator in order to get the length of string that is too much
3. remove the string from the end

```js
function returnStringMultipleEight(originalString) {
    // get the length which should be removed
    const lengthTooMuch = originalString.length % 8;
    
    // calculate the length from first character to the last one to keep
    const lengthToEight = originalString.length - lengthTooMuch;
    
    // get the substring
    const reducedString = originalString.substring(0, lengthToEight);
    
    return reducedString;
}

console.log(returnStringMultipleEight('123456789123'));
console.log(returnStringMultipleEight('12345678912345678912345'));
console.log(returnStringMultipleEight('askldjaflskjflskdfj'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello stack community I Solved my own question the answer is that we just subtract the remainder from the length of the string for instance
return str.slice(0,str.length-str.length%8)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).